# Why is undefined == undefined true but not undefined <= undefined?

Tags: javascript, operators, coercion

In JavaScript this is true:

```
undefined == undefined
```

But this is false:

```
undefined <= undefined
```

At first I thought the `<=` operator included the first one, but I'm guessing it tries to cast it to a number and it fails, but I didn't find any documentation to back this up.

Comment: The first uses the [*abstract equality comparison algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), the second uses the [*abstract relational comparison algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).

Comment: @RobG sounds interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<=` operator [coerces both operands into actual Numbers](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) before performing the comparison *if both operands are primitives* -- while [`==` does **not**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).<sup>1</sup> [Abstract relational comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) is performed which is where this conversion actually happens. The operation [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-tonumber) is performed on `undefined` which yields `NaN` (see the linked table). If you then look at steps 4c and 4d from Abstract relational comparison, if either operand of `<=` is coerced into `NaN`, then `undefined` is returned from Abstract relational comparison. Going back to the first link, you'll see in step 7:

> If *r* is **true** or **undefined**, return **false**. Otherwise, return **true**.

Since Abstract relation comparison returned `undefined`, `<=` evaluates to false.

Less formally, you can see your comparison like this:

```
const first = Number(undefined); //or +undefined
const two = Number(undefined); //this is NaN
NaN <= NaN
```

Since [`NaN == NaN` is never true, nor is `NaN < NaN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values), `NaN <= NaN` is false.

---

<sup>1</sup> `undefined == undefined` returns true based on the abstract [SameValueNonNumber](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-samevaluenonnumber) operation which is used with equality operators if both operads are the same value, but not numbers.

Comment: Sounds right! I should have read ECMA standard first . I'm gonna mark this answer as correct, although I would add why the first comparison (undefined == undefined) is true, which is found in the third step here http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-samevaluenonnumber

Answer (score -1):

Read about **coercion** in JavaScript. About your question, when you apply the equality operator your undefined is coerced to a Boolean. So you got a true result. When you apply the "<=" operator your undefined is coerced to a Number and you get a NaN value and this is the cause of your false result.

Comment: The statement *when you apply the equality operator your undefined is coerced to a Boolean* is incorrect. In the abstract equality comparison algorithm when values are of the same type, the strict equality comparison algorithm is used. And when the values are not numbers, the [*same value non number algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-samevaluenonnumber) is used. The final result is boolean, but no there is coercion. ;-)